# How to create a trigger that listens to a new message in any of the channels within a team in Microsoft Teams and add it to a SharePoint list?

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

How can I trigger a power automate flow from a message in any of the channels within a team of Microsoft teams?

I have tried some options such as: having a trigger 'When a new channel message is added.'. However this does not solve the purpose, as it allows to select only a specific channel within that team. Ideally it should be listening for any message within multiple channels, and adding that message in a SharePoint list.

[When a new channel is added.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INuH4.png)

I have also tried receiving the channels and iterate through them but I cannot use it as a trigger. In this way I can look up all messages throughout all channels and store them in the list. This is not ideal however, cause it has to be manually triggered and appends messages in the list as duplicated items.

[Listing all channels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ2JQ.png)

Is there a way to automatically trigger whenever a new message is added in any of those channels? As it is done by the first case I have tried but not for only one channel.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to trigger Power Automate  whenever a new message is added in any channel. The trigger conditions available are : "When a new channel message is added" and "When a new chat message is added".                         To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in [Teams Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).